# Python - os.system can not use C:\Windows\sysnative when script is compiled to .exe

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, 32bit-64bit, py2exe, os.system

I am working on a tool for automating a repetitive process. I use WSL to parse a file by running a linux tool. My `os.system` call displays `The system cannot find the path specified`.

The call I am using is:

```
os.system('"C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\wsl.exe" cat "%s" | syslog2siptrace > "%s"' % (linuxdir + grepfile, linuxdir + xmlfile))
```

When I run this in the interactive interpreter it works perfectly, but when I compile the script into an `.exe` I get the error.

If I use `system32` instead of `sysnative` in the compiled script then I get : `is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I tried doing this for testing purposes:

```
os.system('dir C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\')
```

And it actually listed the contents of the `C:\Windows\System32` directory (and wsl.exe was in the list) though it did say `Directory of C:\Windows\sysnative`.